# How to change cursorShape when dragging an item out of MouseArea?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I want to change keep changing `cursorShape` when dragging an item out of `MouseArea`.

As you can see in the following code, when  I keep mouse in current `MouseArea`, the `cursorShape` will be altered into `DragCopyCursor`. However, further, if I move the mouse to another mouseArea area, the mouse will become `ArrowCursor` again.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Window {
    width: 300
    height: 300
    visible: true
    color: "#1F1F1F"
    Column {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        Repeater {
            model: 2
            delegate: Rectangle {
                z: mouseArea.drag.active ? 2 : 0
                color: "#aaaaaa"
                width: 300
                height: 50

                MouseArea {
                    id: mouseArea
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    drag.target: rec
                    Binding {
                        when: mouseArea.drag.active
                        mouseArea.cursorShape: Qt.DragCopyCursor
                    }

                    Rectangle {
                        id: rec
                        color: "white"
                        height: parent.height / 2
                        width: parent.width / 2
                        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                        Text {
                            anchors.centerIn: parent
                            text: "test " + index
                            color: "black"
                        }
                        states: [
                            State {
                                when: mouseArea.drag.active
                                AnchorChanges {
                                    target: rec
                                    anchors.verticalCenter: undefined
                                    anchors.horizontalCenter: undefined
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you define `MouseArea` inside `rect`, the `MouseArea` will also move along with `rect` while you are dragging it, thus maintaining the `cursorShape` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `DragHandler` instead of `MouseArea` you can keep your `cursorShape` for the entire duration of the drag. N.B. for `DragHandler` to work, I had to replace the anchoring with explicit calculations for `x` and `y`:

```
    Column {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        Repeater {
            model: 2
            delegate: Rectangle {
                id: frame
                z: dragHandler.active ? 2 : 0
                color: "#aaaaaa"
                border.color: "pink"
                width: 300
                height: 50
                Rectangle {
                    id: rec
                    color: "white"
                    height: parent.height / 2
                    width: parent.width / 2
                    x: (frame.width - width) / 2
                    y: (frame.height - height) / 2
                    Text {
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        text: "test " + index
                        color: "black"
                    }
                    DragHandler {
                        id: dragHandler
                        target: rec
                        cursorShape: Qt.DragCopyCursor
                        onActiveChanged: {
                            if (!active) {
                                rec.x = (frame.width - rec.width) / 2;
                                rec.y = (frame.height - rec.height) / 2;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can I get `mouseX` and `mouseY` at the same time ?

Comment: Whilst not exactly the same, you can infer change via onXChange and onYChange on the Rectangle. Ater awhile, you will recognize scenarios where DragHandler works best, and, in other cases, dragging via MouseArea works best. Having said that, there is a reason why the various handler classes, DragHandler, TapHandler, PinchHandler were written, so, its worth mastering.